# Cast String in multi-dim array to Integer

Tags: ruby, casting, integer, typeerror

I have a variable (`result`) that looks like this when doing `YAML::dump(result)`:

```
responseHeader: 
  status: 0
  QTime: 1
  params: 
    wt: ruby
    q: enid:(15542697739)
response: 
  numFound: 1
  start: 0
  docs: 
  - enid: "15542697739"
```

I want to do a conditional comparison on the `enid` like this:

```
if result["response"]["docs"]["enid"].to_i == num['1']['car']
```

where `num['1']['car']` is an integer.

Whenever I attempt this, I get a TypeError thrown,

```
can't convert String into Integer
(TypeError)
```

even if I attempt

```
result["response"]["docs"]["enid"].to_i
```

or

```
Integer(result["response"]["docs"]["enid"])
```

How do I get my `enid` value converted to an integer so I can make this comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that what's in `result["response"]["docs"]` is NOT a hash and you're addressing it like one. What you need in this case is `result["response"]["docs"][0]["enid"]`. If you want to see why, try `p result["response"]` to see what Ruby data structures are being used at each level. YAML can be a little misleading here even if you've been reading it a while.

Comment: Great! Thanks Peter! Just right. Tried with the [0] term and that works. Hope this helps others as well!